# Two modifiers with String.prototype.match()

Tags: javascript, regex

I've looked far and wide but couldn't figure this out: How can I use two modifiers, say `i` and `g`, with `String.prototype.match()`?

I have this: `var spChar = string.match(/[.:hm]/g);` How can I add the `i` modifier too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write after or before g, the ordering is not necessary:

```
var spChar = string.match(/[.:hm]/gi);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just put both modifiers there:

```
var spChar = string.match(/[.:hm]/ig);
```